# Having problem in getting array value in Solidity

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, blockchain, remix, ethereum-classic

Hi I am New to Solidity!. I have a simple array which adds some numbers in an array

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;
Contract TestArray{
    uint[] public numbers;
    function addNumber(uint number){
        numbers.push(number);
    }
```

This getNumbers() function is returning all the values

```
  function getNumbers() constant returns(uint[]){
        return numbers;
    }
```

But when I am trying to check if the no exists its returning true for only the first value. For the rest of the value it's returning false

```
function checkNoExists (uint no) constant returns(bool){
        for(uint i=0; i<numbers.length; i++){
            if(numbers[i]==no){
                return true;
            } else{
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Please Help!

Comment: Have you tried it using Remix?

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in your `checkNoexists` function. If you check any no other than first  `if(numbers[i]==no)`, this conditions executes to false for `i=0` and returns `false`. The code is working as it should, your logic is incorrect. Use this instead:

```
function checkNoExists (uint no) constant returns(bool){
    for(uint i=0; i<numbers.length; i++){
        if(numbers[i]==no){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it should work.